# Does "take responsibility" need "the"

Tags: word-usage

A journalist asks

> dr. Foutch she said earlier this week
>   that the lag in testing was in fact a
>   failing do you take **responsibility** for
>   that and when can you guarantee that
>   every single American who needs a test
>   will be able to have a test

He responses

> no, I don't **take
>   responsibility** at all. because ...

the "responsibility" has been mentioned, does the response need a "the" in "take responsibility"?

Comment: Please show you effort first, such as a grammar tutorial.

Comment: The article *(**the**)* is ***optional*** in your cited context - but in practice it would very rarely be included (idiomatically, I'd say ***never*** for the journalist asking the question, but *very occasionally* it might be included in the response). But it's not worth trying to analyse this one in terms of "[**a**] responsibility which has been previously mentioned" becoming "[**the**] responsibility."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "take responsibility" is a very common idiomatic phrase, to the point that I think it can be considered a [fixed expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_expression) in English.

While you could use the definite article in this phrase, most people would not, and I think it changes the meaning a little bit.  "take responsibility" implies taking *some* responsibility, but not necessarily all of it (there may be other people who are also responsible).  On the other hand, "take the responsibility" tends to imply that you are taking all of the responsibility (and nobody else is responsible).

Answer (score 1):

Someone more conversant in linguistics can probably explain it better than I, but often when we speak of a quality, no determiner is required.

Other examples are:

I have talent.
I gained experience.
I felt terror.
I learned patience.